# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy - List them individually

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

My problem is that I want to list my custom taxonomies singularly rather than all on one line.

I have the parent taxonomies *`Location`* and *`Venue`* and would like to list them as such:

> Location: example location
>
> Venue: example venue

But the code i am using displays them as:

> example location, example venue

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php  the_terms( $post->ID, 'uk_events' ,  ' '); ?>
```

*`uk_events`* is the custom post type that I am using, *`location`* and *`venue`* are the parent taxonomies in that post type.

Can anyone help with this, it would be very appreciated as I have not found any info on displaying taxonomies like this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure you're meant to pass the custom post type to [`the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms).

Regardless, I think [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) will give you the flexibility that you're after.

Eg:

```
<?php
    $taxList = array("location", "venue");
    foreach ($taxList as $tax) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );      
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            echo "<br/>{$tax}: ";
            $separator = "";
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo "{$separator}{$term->name}";
                $separator ", ";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

NB this was typed out on an iPad so may contain syntax or logic errors as I can't test... But think the idea should be sound enough to help!

---

**Update:** OP advises that the above code is displaying *all* taxonomy terms on each line, which suggests the result from `get_the_terms()` is not filtered by the taxonomy specified at the second parameter.

I wondered if this might be because the taxonomy names are case sensitive, and hence how I've specified them in the `$taxList` array may not be correct, but according to the docco, if this were the case then `get_the_terms()` should return `false` in which case nothing would be output.

So - it seems that it's up to us to filter the results, as follows:

```
<?php
    $taxList = array("location", "venue");
    foreach ($taxList as $tax) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );      
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            echo "<br/>{$tax}: ";
            $separator = "";
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if (strtolower($term->taxonomy) == strtolower($tax)) {// <-- New (redundant!?) filter.
                    echo "{$separator}{$term->name}";
                    $separator ", ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

---

**Update:** A further change might be to automagically pick up the taxonomies used in the current post to avoid typos etc, by updating the first line to this:

```
 $taxList = get_object_taxonomies('uk_events');
```

And then further, this code can then be used for all post types (eg from a call in a template to a function with this code at functions.php) by replacing `'uk_events'` with `$post->post_type`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that code puts the taxonomies on two lines as i wanted, but it is also displaying all of the taxonomies on each line so i get:  Location: example location, example venue

Comment: @MattHelden That's weird, according to [The Codex for `get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) the result should be filtered by the particular taxonomy specified by the second parameter (ie we're passing `$tax`).  We can filter this ourselves though... will update answer.

Comment: @MattHelden can you confirm that `$post`, and hence `$post->ID` contains what you think it does? I wonder if `get_the_terms()` is behaving unexpectedly because it's the _first_ parameter that's incorrect? Do an `echo "<br/>ID: {$post->ID}<br/>";` immediately prior to this code to check?